Issue with Missing broadcasting/auth Route After Installing Reverb and Inertia.js in Laravel 11
I'm working on a Laravel 11 app where I want to use Laravel Reverb for WebSockets. However, I'm encountering an issue with the broadcasting/auth route. Here's the situation:
#1. Fresh Laravel Installation: When I install Reverb in a fresh Laravel app, the broadcasting/auth route is present and works as expected.
#2. Inertia.js Installed First: If I install Inertia.js first (without a starter kit), and then install Reverb, the broadcasting/auth route is missing.
#3. Using Laravel Breeze + Inertia.js: When I install Inertia.js through a starter kit like Laravel Breeze (with Vue and Inertia.js), and then install Reverb, the broadcasting/auth route is present and works fine.
It seems that installing Inertia.js manually before Reverb is causing the broadcasting/auth route to disappear.
Does anyone know what might be causing this issue in scenario #2?
Thanks in advance!

I had a similar issue. It turns out that the broadcasting:install command didn't work as expected because it was supposed to uncomment a "channels" line that didn't exist in the file.
I had this in bootstrap/app.php:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->statefulApi();
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {

    })->create();

The solution was to add this:
channels: __DIR__ . '/../routes/channels.php',

Giving me a final bootstrap/app.php that looks like this:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        channels: __DIR__ . '/../routes/channels.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->statefulApi();
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {

    })->create();

And now the broadcasting/auth route shows up as expected.
Hope this helps!
PS: A lot of the other answers out there say to uncomment BroadCastServiceProvider.php in config/app.php but that doesn't work for a fresh install of Laravel 11.
